# synchronously javascript loading asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I have a demo site built in Word Press.

In the head of the template I injected a script tag that loads a special script.

This script does a document.write to load another script from a server.

The script from the server in turn can do other document.write's to load up to as many as 10.

It is extremely important for these to load like this as these scripts make changes to the page before and thus it eliminates any visible change of content to the visitor.

**Problem:**

I am using a visitor experience recording service that loads my page inside an iframe and overlays it's mouse actions and heat maps.

When viewing the heat maps built in Flash, there is an odd behavior that is causing my script to load asynchronously I presume, cause the result is the page gets cleared because the second document.write is done after DOM ready and thus clears all content.

I am presuming that for some reason the page continues to load as my script runs it's series of document.write's in this particular case.

The only difference from mouse actions recordings that work fine is the presence of the Flash heat map.

I have Googled this to left and right and have found some similar reports some also reporting the added presence of a Flash but not found any clue that would point me towards a solution.

***Has anyone see this behavior before and found a solution?***

*Please do not ask for links as I can only give you the link to the site that has no issues outside the recording service iframe to which I cannot give my credentials to.*

*Note: Asynchronous loading of my script would cause the default content to show for a second or two then be replaced. This would be visible to the visitor and thus unacceptable.*

Comment: Can you add the heat map after the page has fully loaded? It cannot interfere with the loading before. By the way: you shouldn't rely on synchronous script loading.

Comment: I do not control the the recording service site. They load the site into and iframe and inject some JavaScript into it's head at some stage of the parent loading.

Comment: knowing the particular recording service might help answering the question.

Comment: It is ClickTale. I did not want to mention as I did not wish to advertise.